# R text progress bar inessential output

Tags: r, progress-bar, invisible

I am trying to use a text progress bar in an `R` function as follows.

```
pb <- txtProgressBar(min = 0, max = 10, style = 3)

for (i in 1:10) {
Sys.sleep(0.25)
setTxtProgressBar(pb, i)
}
```

I get an unnecessary line of output as follows with style 3, when initiating the progress bar.

```
pb <- txtProgressBar(min = 0, max = 10, style = 3)
  |                                                                       |   0%
```

Is there anyway to avoid this? `invisible` does not seem to work. With other style 1 and 2 such an output in ablesnt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `invisible` after using `capture.output` you can avoid any output:

```
invisible(capture.output(pb <- txtProgressBar(min = 0, max = 10, style = 3)))
```